# What ! sign mean in end of sentences?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

I read much comment or sentences using '**!**' sign, its mean angry or something different? in my country (Indonesia) its use if someone angry, impolite, or instruct something.

Comment: ! is called "exclamation mark" or "exclamation point". It's a punctuation mark we use to indicate an exclamation.

Comment: The exclamation mark was the original emoticon. Fancy that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclamation point/mark is used to indicate strong emotions. Anger is a strong emotion (being surprised too, is a strong emotion). If I am to open a gift and I'm surprised when I found out what the content is, I'd likely exclaim, "Wow!". I am not angry, nor impolite, nor instructing. It's just that the emotion is so strong when I felt surprised.

The clue is 'strong emotion'.

You may refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark) for more information. Google has a lot to offer too! (excitement intended)

Comment: It can also indicate command (imperative).   Shut the door!  or Attention!

Comment: @TRomano Those qualify as instructions.

Comment: @MorganFR: I'm just clarifying for the OP that the punctuation mark can indeed be used for the purpose  of giving an instruction or a command (since one might infer from shin's remark 'not angry, not impolite, nor instructing' that it is not used for that purpose--though I think shin was  simply giving additional contexts, not ruling out the imperative).

Comment: Hold the door!!

Comment: Thanks its works!!! , I think who say that is very happy, right?